# How to do signout button on navigation drawer to redirect me to login page?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, expo

I'm creating a small react native app, when i click on button Logout on menu drawer it should redirect me to login page by passing a function called "signOut" but it shows me this error: "t.signout is not a function and is undefined". 
Btw it works when i call the function on other button on other page.

Code of the drawer Navigator:

```
const drawerNavigator= createDrawerNavigator({
  Chat: {screen: SettingsScreen},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
},
{
  contentComponent:(props) => (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <Button title="Logout" onPress={ () => props.signOut() }/>
//even i tried: this.props.signOut()
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  ),
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}
```

code of the action signOut:

```
export const signOut = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS' })
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**If the signOut function is on the same screen,**

```js
 signOut = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS' })
    });
  }
}
...

const drawerNavigator= createDrawerNavigator({
  Chat: {screen: SettingsScreen},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
},
{
  contentComponent:(props) => (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <Button title="Logout" onPress={ () => this.signOut() }/>
//even i tried: this.props.signOut()
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  ),
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}
```

**If it's on the other screen,**

```js
export function signOut(){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS' })
    });
  }
}
...
```

```js
import { signOut } from 'signoutscreen'
const drawerNavigator= createDrawerNavigator({
  Chat: {screen: SettingsScreen},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
},
{
  contentComponent:(props) => (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <Button title="Logout" onPress={ () => signOut() }/>
//even i tried: this.props.signOut()
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  ),
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for resonding me, but that's not worked also, actually i'm using the mapDispatchToProps method to dispatch my action `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    signOut: () => dispatch(signOut())
  }
}`
so i have to use the props